# Python KeyError when trying to code textual to numerical

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

At first I imported pandas as pd and imported my data set as dF. At first I was getting an unindent error by the elseif. After playing around I got rid of that error and ran into the below error. I am using pythong Jupyter notebook

```
Null = dF.isnull() .any()

dF = dF.drop([["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"]], axis=1)

for column in range(len(list(dF.columns.values))):
    for index, row in dF.iterrows():
        if "No" in row[column] or "Female" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 0
    
        elif "Yes" in row[column] or "Male" in row[column]:
            dF.iloc[index, column] = 1
        
dF.to_excel('Cleaned.xlsx', index=False)
```

**ERROR BELOW**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-076be1113e81> in <module>
  1 Null = dF.isnull() .any()
  2 
----> 3 dF = dF.drop([["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"]], axis=1)
  4 
  5 for column in range(len(list(dF.columns.values))):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4100             level=level,
   4101             inplace=inplace,
-> 4102             errors=errors,
   4103         )
   4104 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   3912         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   3913             if labels is not None:
-> 3914                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   3915 
   3916         if inplace:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   3944                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   3945             else:
-> 3946                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   3947             result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   3948 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in drop(self, labels, errors)
   5338         if mask.any():
   5339             if errors != "ignore":
-> 5340                 raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))
   5341             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   5342         return self.delete(indexer)

KeyError: "[('customerID', 'gender', 'SeniorCitizen', 'Partner', 'Dependents', 'tenure', 'PhoneService', 'MultipleLines', 'InternetService', 'OnlineSecurity', 'OnlineBackup', 'DeviceProtection', 'TechSupport', 'StreamingTV', 'StreamingMovies', 'Contract', 'PaperlessBilling', 'PaymentMethod', 'MonthlyCharges', 'TotalCharges', 'Churn')] not found in axis"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the dF is already populated.  The error you are getting I believe is because you have double arrayed the columns to drop. That's why it's telling you that whole array is not a key in the dF.  Because it's not.

Instead of

```
dF = dF.drop([["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"]], axis=1)
```

Try

```
dF = dF.drop(["customerID", "gender", "SeniorCitizen", "Partner", "Dependents", "tenure", "PhoneService", "MultipleLines", "InternetService", "OnlineSecurity", "OnlineBackup", "DeviceProtection", "TechSupport", "StreamingTV", "StreamingMovies", "Contract", "PaperlessBilling", "PaymentMethod", "MonthlyCharges", "TotalCharges", "Churn"], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! This got rid of the error but didnt give the desired output. I wanted the column headers with a 0 or a 1 in the rows and the output im getting is the only the first column with no header. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some sample input for df?  I feel like we are getting into the logic of the code and it's hard to analyze without replicating the input.